# 2FA on Stack Exchange, Where Is It Or What I am Missing?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

Not sure if this is the right spot to post this, but I have not been able to find how to enable 2FA (such as authy, MS/google authenticator, yubikey etc...) on stack exchange using email authentication. I am aware that I could use SSO through Google or Facebook but would much rather not due to privacy concerns that relate to both companies. The closest I found was this [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275333/why-doesnt-stack-exchange-support-2-factor-authentication-2fa) which recommends SSO which I bet lots of people would not want to use.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## StackExchange does not natively support MFA

As the answer to the question you linked to suggests, SSO providers like Google and Facebook support MFA.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I was thinking I had just missed a button somewhere as the linked post was from 2014 and 2017. Is there any plans to add this then or somewhere where the reasons for not implementing it are laid clear?

Comment: @anotherusername This would be a question for [meta.se]